# Can I make a media player pause/play with another C program by using MPRIS/d-bus or some other means? (on Linux)

Tags: linux, opencv, media-player, dbus

I have a program written in C on Linux that can send/receive messages over BLE. I'd like to have this program communicate with a media player program running at the same time - specifically being able to "pause" and "play" the media player depending on what messages the program receives over the BLE connection. I looked into adding a media player to the C program and found that this is no trivial task. Hence, how can I make my program communicate with another program like a media player? I have read a bit about MPRIS/d-bus and calling media player APIs. This seems like the way to go but I'm unfamiliar and so not sure if it's possible and, if so, how I'd go about implementing it.

Edit: Would it be a better idea to try and make a media player with something like OpenCV?

Answer (score 0):

[Playerctl](https://github.com/altdesktop/playerctl) may come in handy.

> Playerctl is a command-line utility and library for controlling media players that implement the MPRIS D-Bus Interface Specification.